setTargetObjectId not taking full length Id and returning null in toAddress
I have an email template from which I'm trying to trigger an email from a service order. Below are the attributes I have set for SingleEmailMessage
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    message.setWhatId(so.Id);
                    message.setTemplateId((Id)templateId);
                    message.setTargetObjectId(so.customField); //This custom field is a lookup to user
                    message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    emails.add(message);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!emails.isEmpty() && !Test.isRunningTest() && EmailManager.EMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED) {
            Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        }

I checked logs for above execution and all of the above lines are executed. I can also see email invocation.

But email is not triggering to the email id (which is valid and verified). There is an after email logic to attach the email as an attachment which shows the To address as null.

There are no errors in logs and the email is valid and user is active. The only difference I see is that the field actually is of 18 characters but in log in setTargetObjectId it has only 16 characters.
logs:
targetObjectId: 005xxxxxxxxxxC8
Original value in field : 005xxxxxxxxxxC8AAJ
This is the only difference I see. Could this be the reason for the user not being fetched and the to address coming as null? If yes, how to handle it? I'm directly passing the field  (Id) to the setTargetObjectId.

If so.customField is not of type Id casting may help i.e. setTargetObjectId((Id) so.customField). Or change the type to Id.
